continuity for limit of pointwise convergent functions
We Know that "The uniform limit of Continuous Functions is continuous."
and here is its proof:
We want to show that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$, say. The condition for continuity says that

Given any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ so that the following statement is true:
If $ \lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta $ then $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0) \rvert < \epsilon $.

We want to prove this from stuff we know about the $f_n$. We know two things: firstly, that they are continuous, and secondly, that they converge uniformly to $f$.
Since $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, we can find an $N$ that is independent of $y$ so that
$$\lvert f_n(y) - f(y) \rvert < \epsilon/3 $$
for any $n>N$, and any $y$ in the set. (In particular, this is true of both $y=x$ and $y=x_0$.)
Suppose we have such an $n$, $N+1$ will do, and now use that $f_{N+1}$ is continuous. Hence we can find a $\delta$ so that
$$ \lvert f_{N+1}(x)-f_{N+1}(x_0) \rvert < \epsilon/3 $$
whenever $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta$.
We now use the triangle inequality:
$$ \lvert f(x)-f(x_0) \rvert \leqslant \lvert f(x)-f_{N+1}(x) \rvert + \lvert f_{N+1}(x)-f_{N+1}(x_0) \rvert + \lvert f_{N+1}(x_0)-f(x_0) \rvert $$
Supposing now that $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta$, we apply the uniform convergence to the two end terms and the continuity of $f_{N+1}$ to the middle term, and find
$$ \lvert f(x)-f_{N+1}(x) \rvert + \lvert f_{N+1}(x)-f_{N+1}(x_0) \rvert + \lvert f_{N+1}(x_0)-f(x_0) \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon, $$
which is precisely what we wanted.
we know this teorem is not true for pointwise convergence. for example
$f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R $
$f_n(x)=x^n$ are continuous functions that pointwise converges to
$f(x)= 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(1)=1$
f is not continuous.
My question is I see I can write the same proof for pointwise convergent functions and I can't find any mistake in that. I Know when we talk about pointwise convergence N will be dependent of y. but I can take $N_1$ for x and another $N_2$ for $x_0$
then if we take $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$  we get the same point.
I know this have to be wronge. but I can't find my mistake.
what's wrong with my idea? can you help me?

You get a different $N$ for each $x$, but if the $x$’s are in an infinite set, the maximum may not exist. For example, if we fix $x$, the $N_x$ which ensures $x^n<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_x$ is $N_x = \epsilon/\ln x$, but $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} N_x = \infty$, so there can’t be an $N$ which ensures $x^n<\epsilon$ for all $x$.

it's true that we're looking at all x in the nieghborhood of $x_0$ but when looking at the inequality we're taking one of theses x's with $x_0$ so we have two N's at a time. one for x and one for $x_0$ so each time we can take the max.

You can’t just pick one $x$ and use the $N$ for that particular $x$.  To show continuity you need
$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$, which means you need $|f(x)-f_N(x)|<\epsilon/3$ for all $x$ in that neighborhood. So you have infinitely many $x$ for which you need to control the error and hence infinitely many $N_x$.
